# SOA Suite is unable to read the WSDL due to a HTTP error (code 407, Proxy Authentication Required)

Tags: web-services, proxy, soa, bpel, soa-suite

in my composite I inserted a web service. For the WSDL URL of this service I tried to use a link to a document in my company's intranet (`http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl`). After that an error message popped up:

```
Error while reading wsdl file http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl. Exception:
   WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Failed to read WSDL from
   http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl: HTTP connection error code is 407
```

We use a proxy server in our company, so that might be the reason for this error, but I added "10.*" as an exception in my internet options. Also if I open the link in a web browser it shows the WSDL file. I made sure that the option "Use HTTP Proxy Server" in the SOA Suite preferences is not checked. I also tried with a checked box, alas with the same result.

Do you guys have any idea what might cause this? I do realize that this probably is a very unique problem...

When re-opening the composite there's a bit more detailed error message:

```
Failed to find WSDL definition and/or locate WSDL file:
  - WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Failed to read WSDL from
    http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl: HTTP connection error code is 407
  oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException:
  faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Failed to read WSDL from http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl: 
  HTTP connection error code is 407
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Regards,
Carsten

EDIT: Oh snap.. I totally forgot to add the version of the software I use: Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 11.1.1.5.0

Comment: Which tool are you using to try and view the composite?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I added the tool, it's Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 11.1.1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is a proxy issue, try accessing the WSDL from a command line.

E.g. in a Linux box:
`curl http://10.30.3.162/host/sap?wsdl`

You should get the WSDL or an error if you have a proxy issues.